# How to insert into Postgresql each element of array from .tsv file separately?

Tags: python, csv

I would like to insert each element of an array from `.tsv` file separately using Python.

In my example variable which coresponds with array field (row[1]) I have such array:

```
tt0099700,tt0096061,tt0118688,tt0120784
```

The question is how to relate to this variable in ordert to retrieve each element of an array separately. This variable: `row[1] = index 1` corresponds with the number of the field in the row.

Code looks like:

```
tsv_rows_reader = csv.reader(out_file_path, delimiter='\t')
for row in tsv_rows_reader:
    print(row[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

`str.split()` is your friend here. [Docs here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

```py
tsv_rows_reader = csv.reader(out_file_path, delimiter='\t')
for row in tsv_rows_reader:
    as_a_list = row[1].split(',')
    print(as_a_list)
```

that separates the values in `row[1]` into a list, which should suit your needs.